# Custom administration screens in lightswitch (Users and Roles)

Tags: screen, customization, visual-studio-lightswitch, administration

I'm new using Light Switch and I want to know how can I custom my admistration screens. I've looked for info in many websites but I've not find no answer. I'd like to make my own Users and Roles screens getting data from my own database.

Thank you for your answers!